# Building new mobile app with AngularJS +?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Please advice what I need to choose for my mobile app. I'd like to implement my first app for mobile devise as web application. I'm selected AngularJS as for main JS framework.

Question is what I need to choose as for CSS.

For example I'd like to build UI similar to native mobile applications and maybe you could recommend me some good sets of libs js+html for mobile dev.

Thanks
Igor

Comment: there are lots of api that handle mobile applications for responsive design e.g. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) AND [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)